# How to separate the elements of form radios using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying in a thousand ways but I can't get the style or the spaces on that one. I need to use bootstrap.

I need it to look something like this
[image]

---

but mine is

[image: [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRogy.png)]

My code is:

```
<!-- Cuarta fila  -->
<div class="col-6">
   <label for="creditc" class="form-label fw-bold">We accept:</label>
   <div>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-cc-visa"></i>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-cc-apple-pay"></i>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-cc-amazon-pay"></i>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
   <label for="city" class="form-label fw-bold">Message</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" style="overflow:auto;resize:none"></textarea>
   <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Add any notes here.</small>
</div>
```

I know I don't have any styling code applied now or anything but I've tried gutters, spacing, colours (bs-secondary) and nothing works.

Comment: Are you talking about the "radio-buttons" or the "text-area". Both are looking different

Comment: For radio-buttons. Change the `name` and `id` they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I created a complete code as an example, actually there are many ways to make it; I chose the shortest and fastest one for me

```css
.contain-brand{
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #6d757c;
}

.fa-brands{color:#FFF;}

/*edit standard css bootstrap*/
.form-check-input{margin-top: 0!important;}
```

```html
<!--CSS for style-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<!--Code-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
    <label for="creditc" class="form-label fw-bold">We accept:</label>
    <div class="contain-brand p-3 ms-0 rounded-1 row">
        <div class="col p-0 me-3 align-self-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1"><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-visa ms-1"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-0 me-3 align-self-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1"><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-mastercard ms-1"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-0 me-3 align-self-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1"><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-apple-pay ms-1"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-0 me-2 align-self-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tarjeta1" id="tarjeta1"><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-amazon-pay ms-1"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <label for="city" class="form-label fw-bold">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" style="overflow:auto;resize:none"></textarea>
    <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Add any notes here.</small>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```